# Golang concurrency: how to append to the same slice from different goroutines

Tags: concurrency, go, append, goroutine

I have concurrent goroutines which want to append a (pointer to a) struct to the same slice.
How do you write that in Go to make it concurrency-safe?

This would be my concurrency-unsafe code, using a wait group:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
MySlice = make([]*MyStruct)
for _, param := range params {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(param string) {
        defer wg.Done()
        OneOfMyStructs := getMyStruct(param)
        MySlice = append(MySlice, &OneOfMyStructs)
    }(param)
}
wg.Wait()
```

I guess you would need to use go channels for concurrency-safety. Can anyone contribute with an example?

Comment: I believe the response here answers that question well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467445/working-with-slices-of-structs-concurrently-using-references/18469210#18469210

Answer (score 57):

There is nothing wrong with guarding the `MySlice = append(MySlice, &OneOfMyStructs)` with a sync.Mutex. But of course you can have a result channel with buffer size `len(params)` all goroutines send their answers and once your work is finished you collect from this result channel.

If your `params` has a fixed size:

```
MySlice = make([]*MyStruct, len(params))
for i, param := range params {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int, param string) {
         defer wg.Done()
         OneOfMyStructs := getMyStruct(param)
         MySlice[i] = &OneOfMyStructs
     }(i, param)
}
```

As all goroutines write to different memory this isn't racy.

Comment: It's very interesting your last consideration: in case the size of the slice is known and you are just dealing with pointers to the objects, you don't need to use a concurrency mechanism at all

Comment: This does not depend on "slice of pointers": It would work also for "slice of MyStruct". Again the code never writes to the same memory.

Comment: I was assuming that the memory allocation for a pointer is fixed, while the memory allocation for a struct is not fixed. I suppose I am wrong then.

Comment: Hu? What is "fixed"? Any type in Go has a certain memory layout which is determined completely a compile time. No difference between a pointer and something else.

Comment: I've read that you should usually not have buffering in channels, unless there's a specific need.
For your suggestion about the goroutines writing to a shared channel, isn't that a case where you would just deliver synchronously (unbuffered)?

Comment: @DanieleB Can you elaborate why wouldn't you need a concurrency mechanism at all? How else would I map a slice concurrently if I know the length of the original slice? Looking for a more correct/better approach if it exists.

Comment: @Abhijit if you create a new slice of fixed length and you iterate on it to write each element, then you don't need a concurrency mechanism, because there is no concurrency involved. Each element already has its allocated memory and don't concur with other elements.

Comment: @DanieleB If the `getMyStruct` function in the question is a very slow function and I want to run it for all the elements concurrently instead of sequentially, then I'd need a concurrent mechanism, right?

Comment: @Abhijit if such slice is fixed size and local to the function until all elements are written, then you shouldn't need a concurrent mechanism. If you instead you are writing to a slice which is not local to the function, then you would need a concurrent mechanism.

Comment: This solution do not pass the race detection check by `go build -race`

Answer (score 27):

The answer posted by @jimt is not quite right, in that it misses the last value sent in the channel and the last `defer wg.Done()` is never called. The snippet below has the corrections.

https://play.golang.org/p/7N4sxD-Bai

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

type T int

func main() {
    var slice []T
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    queue := make(chan T, 1)

    // Create our data and send it into the queue.
    wg.Add(100)
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            // defer wg.Done()  <- will result in the last int to be missed in the receiving channel
            queue <- T(i)
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        // defer wg.Done() <- Never gets called since the 100 `Done()` calls are made above, resulting in the `Wait()` to continue on before this is executed
        for t := range queue {
            slice = append(slice, t)
            wg.Done()   // ** move the `Done()` call here
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    // now prints off all 100 int values
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

Comment: Coming from the future: why does the @jimt solution not work? The `wg.Done()` is `defer`red, so it is only called after the value is sent through the channel.

What am I missing?

Comment: @chris Can I use an unbuffered channel? `queue := make(chan T)`

Comment: using two different sync primitives is overkill, keeping only channel will do the job

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add that since you know how many values you are expecting from the channel, you may not need to make use of any synchronization primitives. Just read from the channel as much data as you are expecting and leave it alone:

*borrowing @chris' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39065381/2089675)*

```
package main

import "fmt"

type T int

func main() {
    var slice []T

    queue := make(chan T)

    // Create our data and send it into the queue.
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            queue <- T(i)
        }(i)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        select {
        case t := <-queue:
            slice = append(slice, t)
        }
    }

    // now prints off all 100 int values
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

The `select` will block until the channels receives some data, so we can rely on this behaviour to just read from the channel 100 times before exiting.

In your case, you can just do:

```
package main

func main() {
    MySlice = []*MyStruct{}
    queue := make(chan *MyStruct)

    for _, param := range params {
        go func(param string) {
            OneOfMyStructs := getMyStruct(param)
            queue <- &OneOfMyStructs
        }(param)
    }

    for _ := range params {
        select {
        case OneOfMyStructs := <-queue:
            MySlice = append(MySlice, OneOfMyStructs)
        }
    }
}
```